# Problema com Tabbed Panel

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando implementar um código em php,em que busque um parâmetro,crie um tabbed panel de acordo com o parâmetro e dentro desse tabbed panel crie outro tabbed panel,entretando o código está com algum problema que não consegui resolver o segundo tabbed panel não funciona.
Eu clico no Janeiro ,por exemplo, não acontece nada.

```
 <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-669585">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <?php 
    $mes=$_GET["mes"];
    $i;

                for($i=0;$i<14;$i++)
                {
                    if(($mes%12)==1)
                    {?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#panel-21">Janeiro</a>
                    </li><?php
                    }
}
                $mes++;
                }

?>
            </ul>
                <li>
                <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-21">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#panel-3437613" data-toggle="tab">Fósforo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#panel-2" data-toggle="tab">Nitrogênio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#panel-3" data-toggle="tab">Zinco</a>
                </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#panel-4" data-toggle="tab">Potássio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Alguém teria uma solução?